# Extracting the data from DensityHistogram

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have a plot of a `DensityHistogram` from a dataset collected in the lab (stored as `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}`). The data used to construct the histogram is convolved with the impulse response of the detector in the measurement, and I want to deconvolve the data. Is there a way to extract the underlying data from `DensityHistogram` as a matrix/list of lists so that I can deconvolve it with `ListDeconvolve`?

Here is an example with a list of random numbers (I chose about 30% of the size of the dataset I am using to make everything a bit quicker). I am not doing any post-processing and the underlying structure of my data is NOT random, but I think this would be enough to generate a similar sort of plot.

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{1000, 1000}, {100, 1000}, 0], 10000];
DensityHistogram[data, {100}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Comment: I am not sure what MWE stands for.

Comment: Yeah I'll do one now.

Comment: Updated question to include my example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HistogramList[data, ...]` will give you a result of the form

```
{
  {
    {x1, x2, ..., xM}, 
    {y1, y2, ..., yN}
  },
  {
    {c11, c12, ..., c1N},
    ...
    {cM1, cM2, ..., cMN}
  }
}
```

where the `xi` are the boundaries in the x direction, the `yi` are the dividers in the y direction, and the `cij` are the counts of elements in the corresponding bins.

Comment: (This doesn't help if you only have the plot, but I don't want people thinking this is the only way to get the counts, even when they have the original data.)

Comment: How does this differ from something like BinCounts? Obviously there are more options for how you bin the data using HistogramList, and what is returned is different, but if we are considering only the counts section, what is different?

Comment: I've noticed now that BinCounts returns just the c_ij portion that HistogramList returns